# Robot Framework - robotframework-sshlibrary - NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

While installing the robotframework-sshlibrary using pip got the below exception :

```
python -m pip install robotframework-sshlibrary
```

Previously,it has worked well with other libraries.

Exception :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 647, in _prepare_file
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2810, in extras
    return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2853, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2886, in _compute_dependencies
    common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2883, in reqs_for_extra
    if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\_markerlib\markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
    return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Upgraded the pip (20.0.2) and setuptools (44.0.0)
2. Then installed the robotframework-sshlibrary

It was successful.